# Link Asset to solana token

Tags: cryptography, solana

I have solana non-fungible token and a asset (image).

I want to link image with token.

I also want to create smart contract but don't know what it is ?

Anyone knowns how to do this ?

Comment: Not an answer, but here's a doc reference. https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program

Comment: what could be the possible content of smart contract

Comment: It's written in C, C++, or Rust. Amongst other things, I believe it contains a json object which is where the links to the jpgs on your web server are defined.

Comment: According to this, a program contains "instructions". https://docs.solana.com/terminology#program

Comment: In the Solana eco system, smart contracts are called programs.

Comment: I was also referred to this page which shows how its done via metaplex. But thats where things get a little fuzzy for me. I'm a PHP guy which doesn't seem to be supported by Solana at this time. https://www.notion.so/Metaplex-Developer-Guide-afefbc19841744c28587ab948a08cfac

Answer (score 3):

`I want to link image with token.`

1. Upload your image to a service. Here's a good one: https://nft.storage/files/
2. Create json file (https://docs.metaplex.com/nft-standard). Set `uri` field to the image link above
3. Upload the `json file to a service (https://docs.metaplex.com/nft-standard).
4. Create a metadata account for your token:
   It's Program Derived Address (PDA) with a derived key of ['metadata', metadata_program_id, mint_id]. https://docs.metaplex.com/nft-standard

Now you can mint your token to anyone. They should be able to see that NFT in their wallet.

Here is a sample code I do to create metadata account: https://github.com/batphonghan/minter_machine/blob/dbb1e4cd82f47d5062ca14615f0511d4c8631517/minter_server_actix/src/mint_token.rs#L29

`I also want to create smart contract but don't know what it is ?`
It's an on-chain code called program in solana. You do not need it to create a metadata account. Metaplex team has already deployed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's super easy to do this with the Blockchain API.

See the "Create an NFT on Solana" endpoint in [their docs](https://docs.theblockchainapi.com/#tag/Solana-NFT/paths/%7E1v1%7E1solana%7E1nft/post).

[Here](https://github.com/BL0CK-X/the-blockchain-api/tree/main/examples/solana-nft/create-an-nft) are some examples (Python, Javascript).

Here's how to do it in Python:

```
pip install theblockchainapi
```

Then:

```
from theblockchainapi import TheBlockchainAPIResource, SolanaCurrencyUnit

# Get an API key pair for free here: https://dashboard.theblockchainapi.com/
MY_API_KEY_ID = None
MY_API_SECRET_KEY = None
BLOCKCHAIN_API_RESOURCE = TheBlockchainAPIResource(
    api_key_id=MY_API_KEY_ID,
    api_secret_key=MY_API_SECRET_KEY
)


def example():
    """
    This example creates a new wallet, gets an airdrop to mint an NFT, and then mints an NFT.
    """
    try:
        assert MY_API_KEY_ID is not None
        assert MY_API_SECRET_KEY is not None
    except AssertionError:
        raise Exception("Fill in your key ID pair!")

    # Create a wallet
    secret_key = BLOCKCHAIN_API_RESOURCE.generate_secret_key()
    public_key = BLOCKCHAIN_API_RESOURCE.derive_public_key(
        secret_recovery_phrase=secret_key
    )
    print(f"Public Key: {public_key}")
    print(f"Secret Key: {secret_key}")

    # Get an airdrop on the devnet in order to be able to mint an NFT
    BLOCKCHAIN_API_RESOURCE.get_airdrop(public_key)

    # We need to make sure this has time to process before minting the NFT!
    import time
    time.sleep(25)

    def get_balance():
        balance_result = BLOCKCHAIN_API_RESOURCE.get_balance(public_key, unit=SolanaCurrencyUnit.SOL)
        print(f"Balance: {balance_result['balance']}")
    get_balance()

    # Mint an NFT
    nft = BLOCKCHAIN_API_RESOURCE.create_nft(
        secret_recovery_phrase=secret_key,
        nft_name="The Blockchain API",
        nft_symbol="BLOCKX",
        nft_url="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1441903262509142018/_8mjWhho_400x400.jpg"
    )
    print("NFT: ", nft)
    print(f"You can view the NFT here: {nft['explorer_url']}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```